# Manage Azure vnic in python

Tags: python, azure

i need to attach a specific network security group into a set of vnic present in my azure resource group, how can i do?

usually i use this module:

```
import msrestazure
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import DiskCreateOption

def get_credentials_sys(sid):
    subscription_id = sid
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret= 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy',
        tenant= 'wwwwwwwwwwww'
    )
    return credentials, subscription_id

def print_item(group):
    """Print a ResourceGroup instance."""
    print("\tName: {}".format(group.name))
    print("\tId: {}".format(group.id))
    print("\tLocation: {}".format(group.location))
    print("\tTags: {}".format(group.tags))
    print_properties(group.properties)

def print_properties(props):
    """Print a ResourceGroup properties instance."""
    if props and props.provisioning_state:
        print("\tProperties:")
        print("\t\tProvisioning State: {}".format(props.provisioning_state))
    print("\n\n")

def main():


    try:
        credentials, subscription_id = get_credentials_sys(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
    except AuthorizationFailed:
        print("Credential not allowed")

    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    for item in resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(MY_RESOURCE_GROUP):
        if "networkInterfaces" in item.id :
            if "NIC_TO_FILTER" in item.name:
                pass
            else:
                print("I WANT ADD THE NETWORK SECURITY GROUP, HERE")
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My goal is, filter all vnic present in my resource group, filtering it by name, then i want add it one specific network security group.
Is possible?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Answer (score 0):

Of curse, it's possible. You can get all the NICs in the resource group and get the NSG that you want to associate to the NICs. Then you can filter the NIC with its name in the for loop, associate the NSG and then update it.

I assume you want to associate one NSG to the NICs filtered in the resource group. Then the example code here:

```
rg_name = "xxxx"
nsg_name = "xxxx"
nic_list = network_client.network_interfaces.list(rg_name)
nsg = network_client.network_security_groups.get(rg_name, nsg_name)

for nic in nic_list:
  if (nic.name == "xxxx"):             # filter the NICs in your condition
    nic.network_security_group = nsg
    network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(resource_group, nic.name, nic)
```